# optimal way to copy mysql table to another instance? (not live)

Tags: mysql

I have multiple hard drives. One is getting full so i'll need to move a database or two to the other harddrive. The databases are all in their own folder. One database is 15+gb the others are ~.5gb. What is the most optimal way to move them? I am hoping i can simply write create database and then copy/write over the blank database but i don't know if it will work or just appear to work causing me trouble later.

What is the most optimal way to copy one database to another harddrive. Each harddrive is their own instance/port. I hope I don't need to write a script to copy every table over but i do know many have only 3 tables so it wouldnt be hard. Also this isnt live so i can stop/restart/lock anything i want

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Navicat to dump a database which generates a flat sql file... then on the new server i create the new db and run a query using the contents of the sql file... you can use phpmyadmin as a free solution: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=226796